# С++ вызов стороннего метода в методе main

Tags: c++

Есть программа, не могу понять что не нравится компилятору. На Java я подобное сделал бы за 5 минут.
Прощу прощения, если где-то откровенно туплю, ибо с C++ начал общаться только сегодня
В теории в main должен вызываться метод randomSpeak.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "\a" << endl;
        int randomInt = 0 + rand()%10;

        //Строка ниже упорно выдаёт ошибку
        randomSpeak(randomInt);
        Sleep(1000);
    }


    return 0;
}

void randomSpeak (int s)
{

    if (s == 0)
    {
        cout << "0&?!?!?!?" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 1)
    {
        cout << "1!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 2)
    {
        cout << "Винда повисла!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 3)
    {
        cout << "3!!!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 4)
    {
        cout << "Надо было ставить Linux!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 5)
    {
        cout << "5 Microsoft!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 6)
    {
        cout << "6 и винда готова!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 7)
    {
        cout << "format c:/ is starting..." << endl;
    }
    if (s == 8)
    {
        cout << "8!!" << endl;
    }

    if (s == 9)
    {
        cout << "9!!" << endl;
    }
    if (s == 10)
    {
        cout << "10" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка-то? А пока вангую, что нужно мейн перенести ниже функции randomSpeak

Answer (score 5):

Вангую, что ошибка в том, что `main` не знает о функции `randomSpeak`.

Есть два пути ее исправления.

Первый - просто перенести все определение функцию `randomSpeak` выше функции `main`.

Второй - объявить функцию `randomSpeak` до `main`-а. Для этого нужно выше `main`-а добавить одну строку, оставив все остальное неизменным:

```
void randomSpeak (int s);
```

Comment: Спасибо! ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо тебе! Заработало.
Впредь буду знать о такой особенности плюсов! Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Определите метод main после метода randomSpeak. На Java у вас и так все сработает, но вот в C++ можно использовать только объявленные методы